# R: Add column to data frame depending on other string variable

Tags: r, dataframe, character, addition

I have a data frame with a character column 1 (& several numerical columns).
This column 1 contains IDs like the following: BIS12; HK/FF; 310; BIS101; 412 ...

Now I want to add a factor column to the data frame, to sort these IDs in 2 groups. I want something like "if a number" -> 0; "if it contains 'BIS'" -> 1.

Can anyone help me with this? I found some solutions for sorting numbers or looking for defined strings, but nothing that general...

Thanks for every tip!

Comment: Just do `as.integer(grepl("B1S", data$Col))`

Comment: How should it handle "HK/FF"? It's neither "like a number" nor "contains 'BIS''.

Comment: I tried: `combine$group <- as.integer(grepl("B1S", combine$ID))`. This adds the colulmn group, but there are 0s in every row now. So how can I deal with the numbers, which should be coded as 1? "HK/FF" should be also coded as 1 or 3 (I am not sure yet, but hope I can do it when I know how to specify that some characters should be coded as one number)....

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure that this is what you're looking for, but this is how I would tackle this with a data.frame. First I would define the default value I want for the common case, then I would write some rules to update for the exception cases e.g. BIS, or numbers.

```
# sample data
dt <- data.frame(V1 =c("BIS12", "HK/FF", "310"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# default is not a number, and not BIS e.g. 2
dt$classifier <- 2

# numbers: 0, bis: 1
dt$classifier[!is.na(as.integer(dt$V1))] <- 0

# BIS
dt$classifier[grepl("BIS", dt$V1)] <- 1

# result
dt
```

Is this helpful?

Best,
Jonny

Comment: Yes this was very helpful! Thank you Jonny!